# How can I demean variables by group in patsy?

Tags: python, regression, patsy

for a regression I want to subtract group specific means from the (many) right side variables (they are interactions).

Without group specificity this is easy of course.

```
y, X = dmatrices('lhs ~ center(x1 * k1)', df)
```

How could I do this with group specific means? The Problem is that the right hand side contains many interaction terms which I cannot naively create upfront.

So I would like to do something like this upfront:

```
df['x1_times_k1'] = df['x1'] * df['k1']
df['x1_times_k1_centered'] = df.groupby('group')['x1_times_k1'].transform('mean')

y, X = dmatrices('lhs ~ x1_times_k1_centered', df)
```

But it won't be feasible, any suggestions?

**EDIT** 
Alternatively: is there a way to standardize the data by group in scikit?

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler